# Error in C: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: android, c, operating-system, kernel

I am working on a project that modifies part of the Android OS, and when I tried to implement a new system call to return the status of all the processes, I encountered the following error:

```
kernel/sys.c: error: array tpye has incomplete element type.
```

What I did in sys.c is the following:

```
/***previous code in sys.c***/

SYSCALL_DEFINE2(new_syscall, struct info __user*, buf, int __user*, nr){
    if(!buf || !nr) return -EINVAL;

    int nr_copy;
    int success;

    success = copy_from_user(&nr_copy, nr, sizeof(int));
    if(success == 0) return -EINVAL;
    if(nr_copy < 1) return -EINVAL;

    struct info buf_copy[nr_copy];  /*************

    return 0;
}
```

Complier complained about the line marked with stars.

My info.h file looks like this:

```
    #ifndef __LINUX_INFO_H
    #define __LINUX_INFO_H

    struct info {
        long state;         
        pid_t pid;          
        pid_t parent_pid;       
    };

    #endif
```

I tried including the info.h in sys.c, but it didn't help at all. Can anyone provide me some directions on what I should look into?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array type has incomplete element type error when compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386539/array-type-has-incomplete-element-type-error-when-compiling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What compiler are you using? Dynamically sized arrays are a newish C feature that might not be supported. OTOH, they are allocated on the stack, and that is a *very* scarce commodity in-kernel. You should allocate memory for the array via `kmalloc` or one of its ilk.

Comment: It's not dynamically allocated array, it's a fixed size array of length nr_copy. Good point for kmalloc

Comment: @user1926344, you are getting the size for the array the line above it's definition, unless my kernel-C is way off by now...

Comment: nr_copy is a variable declared as int, so buf_copy[nr_copy] is not a fixed size array at compile time.

Comment: oh i see the problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly declaring state as a long int.

```
long state;
```

to

```
long int state;
```

Comment: There are two __user* pointers.  info __user*  and int  __user*

Comment: Both `long state` and `long int state` mean exactly the same thing in C.

Comment: @vonbrand,  Check that assumption with code.  Depends on the hardware AND operating sytem:   sizeof(int) on a 286 returns 2    sizeof(int) on a 16bitOS on a 386 returns 2, but 4 on a 32bit OS.  sizeof(int) on my x86_64 returns 4, but sizeof(long int) returns 8.

Comment: completely irrelevant. As I said, in C `long` is exactly the same as `long int`, if you omit the type it defaults to `int` (yes, this comes from C's prehistory).